# Can I use Service Account with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, jwt

Since few day I am trying to get user profile with my C# using Using [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications with JWT](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

For google drive i know that we can use server to server method, but i am not sure for Google Analytics. Can we use it ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can!

```
Service Accounts

Useful for automated/offline/scheduled access to Google Analytics data for your own account. For example, to build a live dashboard of your own Google Analytics data and share it with other users.
There are a few steps you need to follow to configure service accounts to work with Google Analytics:

1. Register a project in the APIs Console.
2. In the Google APIs Console, under the API Access pane, create a client ID with the Application Type set to Service Account.
3. Sign-in to Google Analytics and navigate to the Admin section.
4. Select the account for which you want the application to have access to.
5. Add the email address, from the Client ID created in the APIs Console from step #2, as a user of the selected Google Analytics account.
6. Follow the instructions for Service Accounts to access Google Analytics data.
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. See [Service Accounts have arrived](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/03/service-accounts-have-arrived.html).

> > Service accounts are currently supported by the following Google developer services:
> >
> > - Google Cloud Storage
> > - Google Prediction API
> > - Google URL Shortener
> > - Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server
> > - Google APIs Console
> > - Google APIs Client Libraries for Python, Java, and PHP
> >
> > Over time, more Google APIs and client libraries will be supported.

Sign up for [Google Developers Blog](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/) and the [Analytics Blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/) feeds. They will post when GA is opened to service accounts, if it ever is.

Comment: Thanks JK for comments, I am able to get access_token using JWT but problem is that i am not able to get user's profile using "prn:xxx@gmail.com". What might be the problem ?